# Outlook changing HTML font size after sending

Tags: windows-7, fonts, microsoft-outlook-2007, html, exchange-2007

On a Domain Computer running Windows 7, Outlook 2007, connected to Exchange 2007, when sending embedded HTML from Outlook the font size gets shrunk before delivery and when it appears in the sent mail box.

Has anyone else had this issue and/or know how to solve it please?

Additional: after logging in on another domain acct on the same computer I have come to find out that outlook does not change the font size of the HTML. The issue seems to be isolated to just this particular user, on just this host computer. Possible button mash?